# Using Xquery in Scalar Value Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have the below Query that returns the information that I need, but I need to use this query In a Scalar Valued function to use the returned values in a computed column.

The XML Column is in the same table and I need to insert the values from Settings into a column named Directions

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS als )
SELECT
 a.a.value('@Settings', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Settings]

FROM Base AS X
    CROSS APPLY X.BaseXML.nodes('als:Name') a(a)
```

The Function I was trying, but not getting anywhere was

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ChooseRevision](@lineId int) Returns integer As
Begin
Return (WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS als )
SELECT
 a.a.value('@Settings', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Settings]

FROM Base AS X
    CROSS APPLY X.BaseXML.nodes('als:Name') a(a)
Where LineId = @lideid
)
End

GO
```

How would you include the query inside a scarlar function to use as a computed column?

```
<als:Doc xmlns:als="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SchemaVersion="0.1" Settings="First Test" Title="Recovery Loop">
  <als:Base Rev="0" Id="201" />
  <als:Number TimeStamp="2013-01-21T15:08:00">
    <als:Member Name="Club Run" DirId="123" />
  </als:Number>
  </als:Doc>
```

Comment: Can you post the schema of the table, an example XML value and the expected results? Is LineId a tag inside the XML or a column in dbo.Base? Is there always only one `als;Name` node inside each XML value?

Comment: lineid in the pk of the table (another column in the table) als;name is the only value to return in this sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is only one `als:Name` node per XML value you can write this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ChooseRevision](@lineId int) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @r VARCHAR(50);
  WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS als)
  SELECT
   @r = BaseXML.value('als:Doc[1]/@Settings', 'VARCHAR(50)') 
  FROM Base
  WHERE LineId = @lineId;
  RETURN @r;
END
```

If you are planning to use this function within the dbo.Base table itself, you should use this version instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ChooseRevision](@xml XML) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @r VARCHAR(50);
  WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS als)
  SELECT @r = @xml.value('als:Doc[1]/@Settings', 'VARCHAR(50)') 
  RETURN @r;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that although you may know that your select query will only return one result, the database does not. Consider this sample schema

```
CREATE TABLE Base (BaseXML XML, Settings INT);
INSERT Base VALUES ('<root settings="1"><a>SomeXML</a></root>', NULL);
```

You know that settings only appears once in the root, so this

```
SELECT  a.a.value('@settings', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Settings]
FROM    Base X
        CROSS APPLY X.BaseXML.nodes('root') a(a);
```

Will only return one result (for each row), however, if you take this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Base2 (BaseXML XML, Settings INT);
INSERT Base2 VALUES ('<root><a settings="1">SomeXML</a><a settings="2">Some More XML</a></root>', NULL);
```

An almost identical query will return 2 rows:

```
SELECT  a.a.value('@settings', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Settings]
FROM    Base2 X
        CROSS APPLY X.BaseXML.nodes('root/a') a(a);
```

Therefore your function cannot work as a scalar function. You need to tell SQL that you are only expecting one (the first) value back by using [1]:

```
SELECT  BaseXML.value('/root[1]/@settings[1]', 'INT') AS Settings
FROM    Base;
```

**[SQL FIddle to demonstrate multiple return values](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c19d1/8)**

I would suggest the best way to do this though is rather than send the LineID as a parameter, to send the XML itself. Since you want a computed column you can just send the XML data and save a needless second query of the table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseBaseSettings (@XML XML)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @XML.value('/root[1]/@settings[1]', 'INT');
END;
```

You will probably need to handle your XML Namespaces in here, but for example's sake I have skipped this.

Finally you can create your computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE Base 
(   BaseXML XML, 
    Settings AS dbo.ParseBaseSettings(BaseXML)
);
```

**[SQL Fiddle of final solution](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/769b8/1)**

**EDIT**

With your actual XML data I have compiled this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseBaseSettings (@XML XML)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret NVARCHAR(50);        
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS als)
    SELECT  @Ret = @XML.value('/als:Doc[1]/@Settings', 'NVARCHAR(50)');

    RETURN @Ret;
END;
```